# D3.js Add a Shaded Timeframe Region Behind A Line on a Line Graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, linegraph

I am using D3.js (v4) to create a simple line graph that looks like this:

[Simple Line Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RaN2z.jpg)

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c19664p3/)

I would like to add a second data set that shows a shaded timeframe region behind the line.

The data would look something like this:

```
RangeStart: 31-Mar-18
RangeEnd: 16-Apr-18
Label: "Golden Period"
Color: "#3cfb34"
```

- RangeStart represents the start of the shaded region on the graph.
- RangeEnd represents the end of the shaded region on the graph.
- Label is the text that appears on top of the shaded region
- Color is the color of the shaded region

And the chart would output the shaded region (with the label) like this:

[Simple Line Graph with Shaded Timeframe Region](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GUusC.jpg)

How can I accomplish something like this?

Thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a rectangle and a text before adding the line:

```
// ADD TIMEFRAME
var timeframe = {
    RangeStart: parseDate('31-Mar-18'),
    RangeEnd: parseDate('16-Apr-18'),
    Label: "Golden Period",
    Color: "#3cfb34"
};

var gTimeframe = svg.append("g").attr("class", "timeframe");

gTimeframe.append("rect")
    .attr("x", x(timeframe.RangeStart))
    .attr("y", 0)
    .attr("width", x(timeframe.RangeEnd) - x(timeframe.RangeStart))
    .attr("height", height)
    .style("fill", timeframe.Color);

gTimeframe.append("text")
    .attr("x", x(timeframe.RangeStart) + 5)
    .attr("y", 15)
    .text(timeframe.Label);
// END TIMEFRAME
```

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/04db5urw/3/).

If you need to add multiple timeframes, store them in an array, and use a D3 data bind like this:

```
// ADD TIMEFRAME
var timeframes = [
  {
    RangeStart: parseDate('31-Mar-18'),
    RangeEnd: parseDate('16-Apr-18'),
    Label: "Golden Period",
    Color: "#3cfb34"
  },
  {
    RangeStart: parseDate('20-Apr-18'),
    RangeEnd: parseDate('3-May-18'),
    Label: "Other Period",
    Color: "steelblue"
  },
];

var gTimeframes = svg
    .selectAll("g.timeframe")
  .data(timeframes).enter()
    .append("g").attr("class", "timeframe");

gTimeframes.append("rect")
    .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.RangeStart); })
    .attr("y", 0)
    .attr("width", function(d) { return x(d.RangeEnd) - x(d.RangeStart); })
    .attr("height", height)
    .style("fill", function(d) { return d.Color; });

gTimeframes.append("text")
    .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.RangeStart) + 5; })
    .attr("y", 15)
    .text(function(d) { return d.Label; });
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/04db5urw/5/)

Comment: This works great. Thank you! Do you know how I can add multiple timeframes to the chart

Comment: I've updated the answer with an option to add multiple timeframes by using an array and a data bind.